# Do bosses spawn in survival?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I've been playing through the levels in Survival Mode, with the hopes of scoring some unique or interesting pets.  However, my current strategy is very "hands off" - I'm not paying full attention to the game, and I'm leveling two characters which I can't be controlling at the same time.

There are certain levels in Dungeon Defenders where bosses spawn - the first being the Demon Lord in the Alchemical Laboratory.

If I play this map in survival mode, does the boss still spawn?  Does he spawn every X waves, or just once?  If he does spawn, does he spawn at the same wave he spawned on in the campaign mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are playing those levels on survival mode, the bosses do not spawn. The waves of mobs increase in both number and difficulty (health/resistances/damage) as the waves go on.

Also there is a cap for the number of waves, 25 for campaign levels, 30 for shards levels.

It was also very popular to farm the Alchemy Lab for loot drops early on in the game's timeline. Now other methods are more profitable/yield better gear drops.